# Viewpager + button to new Activity

Tags: java

So, I wrote code with Viewpager in one Activity. I placed there button to new Activity but it doesn' t work and I don' t know why.

I tried use standard Intent function, there's no warnings or errors but application crash when I use the button. I don't know where the problem is?
Second Activity is standard, new Activity and button has some id and method onClick.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class customAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public int[] levels = {R.drawable.ip_sem_jeden, R.drawable.ip_sem_dwa, R.drawable.ip_sem_trzy, R.drawable.ic_sem_czt,
            R.drawable.ip_sem_piat, R.drawable.ip_sem_szes};

    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public customAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return levels.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_select_stage, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(levels[position]);
        container.addView(item_view);
        Button button = (Button) item_view.findViewById(R.id.startGameButton);
        button.setText(ctx.getString(R.string.nameSemestr) + ++position);
        return item_view;


    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: We need the logcat in order to deduce what caused the error. . .

Comment: I don't know how can I copy these much text here. Take screens or copy only first red lines?

Comment: Copy 20-30 lines, include the start cause it says what the exception is, and `caused by` part because this will point to the line of the error.

Comment: Vucko, thank you for Your commitment. I have solved a problem. The problem was memory.I have placed too big pictures inside layouts and there have been text (something like) 'memory out of bound'. I have resized images and now everything perfectly work.

Comment: Cool bro, have a nice day.